# Android recyclerview - cant able to navigate items using accessibility focus

Tags: android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

In my app, there is a recyclerview for which we have added setCollectionInfo to have additional list info when navigating using accessibility (Talkback turned ON).

Adding setCollectionInfo causes recyclerview scroll issue.
I am unable to navigate items till the end of the recyclerview, only able to navigate till the item that is visible on the screen.
Removing setCollectionInfo fixes the issue.

Could anyone help to provide solution to resolve the scroll issue.